# How to test file upload in java

Tags: java, testing, vaadin, test-bench

How can I upload a specific file in **vaadin test bench case.** that means Select a specific file from Window pop up and get that file uploaded.

Comment: You mean restrict by type?

Comment: Nop Not restrict by Type Just Say you have Created a File Named *abc* , type can be any and you want that particular file to be uploaded From Vaadin test bench case my Exact point is how to make vaadin test bench know the path where that particular file is located, and will select that file by opening window popup @  soorapadman

Comment: You search for a plugin that helps you uploading files like EasyUpload.

Comment: ANY Idea by selenuim Driver .?